# Click web page jquery button using vba excel

Tags: jquery, excel, html, vba

I need some help with my vba excel code:

```
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
    For Each Anchor In ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
         If InStr(Anchor.outerHTML, "CategoryIDName-popup") > 0 Then
            Anchor.Focus
            SendKeys "{DOWN}"
            SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            Anchor.Click
            Anchor.FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
            Exit For
         End If
     Next Anchor
```

I've already tried sendkeys, click, or even ondblclick, but nothing is working. Here is the html code:

< DIV id=CategoryIDName-popup class="input-group-addon btn" tabIndex=1 jQuery111308417279745872946="287">
< I class="fa fa-search"< /I>
< /DIV>

Any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ieDoc.getElementById("CategoryIDName-popup").FireEvent "onmouseover"
ieDoc.getElementById("CategoryIDName-popup").FireEvent "onmousedown"
ieDoc.getElementById("CategoryIDName-popup").FireEvent "onmouseup"
```